# Android Studio 3.0 mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.gridview.GridView Error

Tags: java, android, gridview

when I updated Android Studio to 3.0 the GridView stopped working.
This is the repository: https://github.com/EmirWeb/parchment

Error: 
android.view.InflateException:
 Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.gridview.GridView

```
 <mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.gridview.GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/"
                android:id="@+id/grid_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@color/blu"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                parchment:cellSpacing="10dp"
                parchment:gravity="left"
                parchment:numberOfViewsPerCell="1"
                parchment:orientation="horizontal"
                parchment:snapPosition="start" />
```

---

```
dependencies {
    compile 'mobi.parchment:parchment:1.6.9@aar'

}

and

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }


    }
}
```

Solutions?

Comment: share your code.

Comment: have you included this library in your gradle ?

Comment: Done! I updated the question

Comment: I have and it always worked until the update

Comment: `mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.gridview.GridView` check this path exist or not in your project.

Comment: In which folder should I find it?

Comment: select Ctrl key and click on above path if it not clickable than you set wrong path  to your root xml.

Comment: in the XML file when I click on  <mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.gridview.GridView with Ctrl key find all class.

Comment: i post my ans, check this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163626/discussion-between-hemant-parmar-and-massimiliano-allegretti).

Comment: The problem is  xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/" because if I remove the parchment options GridView works. Which address should I put?

Comment: It should be `xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Comment: @MikeM. not working

Comment: Try cleaning/rebuilding. If that doesn't fix it, you'll want to post the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

you are set wrong attribute  `parchment:orientation` & `parchment:gravity` in xml.

```
 <mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.gridview.GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/"
                android:id="@+id/grid_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:background="@color/blu"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
                android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                parchment:cellSpacing="10dp"
                parchment:gravity="left"
                parchment:numberOfViewsPerCell="1"
                parchment:orientation="horizontal"
                parchment:snapPosition="start" />
```

above `mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.gridview.GridView` class does not have attribute like `orientation` & `gravity` so either be remove or use attribute like this

```
android:gravity="left"                
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

here is the reference of class :

```
package mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.gridview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.Adapter;

import mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.AbstractAdapterView;
import mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.AdapterViewHandler;
import mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.AdapterViewInitializer;
import mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.AdapterViewManager;
import mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.OnSelectedListener;
import mobi.parchment.widget.adapterview.SnapPosition;

/**
 * Created by Emir Hasanbegovic
 */
public class GridView<ADAPTER extends Adapter> extends AbstractAdapterView<ADAPTER, Group> implements OnLongClickListener, OnClickListener, OnSelectedListener, AdapterViewHandler {

    public GridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GridView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    public GridView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected AdapterViewInitializer<Group> getAdapterViewInitializer(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        final GridAttributes gridAttributes = new GridAttributes(context, attributeSet);

        final int numberOfViewsPerCell = gridAttributes.getNumberOfViewsPerCell();
        final boolean isViewPager = gridAttributes.isViewPager();
        final boolean isVertical = gridAttributes.isVertical();
        final int cellSpacing = (int) gridAttributes.getCellSpacing();
        final boolean isCircularScroll = gridAttributes.isCircularScroll();
        final boolean snapToPosition = gridAttributes.isSnapToPosition();
        final int viewPagerInterval = gridAttributes.getViewPagerInterval();
        final SnapPosition snapPosition = gridAttributes.getSnapPosition();
        final boolean selectOnSnap = gridAttributes.selectOnSnap();
        final boolean selectWhileScrolling = gridAttributes.selectWhileScrolling();
        final boolean isTop = gridAttributes.isTop();
        final boolean isBottom = gridAttributes.isBottom();
        final boolean isLeft = gridAttributes.isLeft();
        final boolean isRight = gridAttributes.isRight();
        final GridLayoutManagerAttributes gridLayoutManagerAttributes = new GridLayoutManagerAttributes(numberOfViewsPerCell, isCircularScroll, snapToPosition, isViewPager, viewPagerInterval, snapPosition, cellSpacing, selectOnSnap, selectWhileScrolling, isVertical, isTop, isBottom, isLeft, isRight);

        final AdapterViewManager adapterViewManager = new AdapterViewManager();
        final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, this, adapterViewManager, gridLayoutManagerAttributes);

        final AdapterViewInitializer<Group> adapterViewAdapterViewInitializer = createAdapterViewInitializer(context, isViewPager, adapterViewManager, gridLayoutManager, isVertical);
        return adapterViewAdapterViewInitializer;
    }
```

Hope you get my point.Happy coding!!

Comment: The problem is  xmlns:parchment="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/" because if I remove the parchment options GridView works. Which address should I put?

Comment: yes remove this line and import it again, it will resolve your issue.

Comment: If I remove this line, android studio does not resolve automatically the issue